# Conectando a base de datos con socket.io y node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, socket.io

¿Esta es la forma correcta de conectarme a una base de datos?, si bien me funcionó... muchas veces me encuentro con respuestas: "esta forma es obsoleta", y mi pregunta es esa, esta es una buena forma de conectarse a una bd y de realizar consultas? (o la única), me pareció muy sencillo y rápido quisiera saber si es la manera correcta solamente.

Este es mi archivo del servidor donde realizo consultas y recibo las peticiones del cliente:

```
var app = require('express')();
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.use(express.static('./public'));
var users = [];
var nicks = new Array();
var mysql = require("mysql");


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "prueba"
});



con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error connecting to Db');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connection established');
});


con.query(
    'SELECT * FROM canales',
    function(err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(rows);
    }
);



io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

socket.on('room', function(room) {

    socket.join(room);

});


});


});



http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: No veo ningún problema con tu código aparte de que no es algo para usar en producción. Como ejemplo y para arrancar está bien.

Comment: Ok, gracias por responder bro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que haces es completamente válido. Por ejemplo, un chat en Node.js con Socket.io debe conectarse a la base datos **al correr** la aplicación para que guarde los mensajes. Otra opción mucho mejor sería tener una [API](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaz_de_programaci%C3%B3n_de_aplicaciones) para manejar acciones sobre el chat. Aún así, lo que haces es válido y no entiendo el por qué *"obsoleto"*; yo usaría las palabras *"poco recomendado"* en su lugar.

Hay un concepto llamado "[Separación de intereses](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separaci%C3%B3n_de_intereses)" que, básicamente nos anima a separar concientemente una aplicación en partes distintas, cada una con su funcionamiento propio. Esto tiene mucho que ver con el "[Principio de responsabilidad única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica)" (SRP) que, aunque está pensada para el término *"clases"*, se puede usar para un módulo, etc. y que, nos dice que una determinada *clase*, *módulo* o afines, debe tener una sola responsabilidad. De esta manera, tenemos un [bajo acoplamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoplamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)) en nuestra aplicación, incrementando así **enormemente** la calidad de nuestro software en distintos aspectos: arquitectura, diseño y aspectos post desarrollo (mantenimiento, escalabilidad).

Tu aplicación debería tener una API que se encargue de las acciones sobre el chat. Esta API debería ser privada y accederse a ella mediante un método de autenticación; yo te recomiendo [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token).

```
io.on('message', ({ author, room, message, token }) => {
  fetch ('/michat/v1/message/new', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  })
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) {
      // hacer un broadcast a los usuarios de dicha sala
    } else {
      // mandar un mensaje de error de credenciales
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta bro! acepte tu respuesta.